# Different method toString for different types of class

Tags: scala, generics

I need to have method toString be different for Strings and for Numbers (Int, Double, Float). For Strings it just convert to string and for numbers it multiply each element of list on number and convert to string. When I try to make it work at least for Int, it says 'Method 'toString' overrides nothing'.

```
class Seq[T : Ordering] (initialElems: T*) {
  override def toString(implicit ev: T <:< Int): String = {
    elems.foreach((i:T) => fac(factors)*i).toString
  }

  val elems = initialElems.sorted

  def concat(a:Seq[T]) = new Seq(a.elems ++ this.elems:_*)

  val factors = ListBuffer[Int](1)

  def fac(xs: ListBuffer[Int]): Int = {
    var i=0
    var sum = 1
    while (i < xs.length) {
      sum *= xs(i)
      i += 1
    }
    sum
  }

  def multy(a: Int)(implicit ev: T <:< AnyVal): Unit = {
    factors += a
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.foreach` returns `Unit`, so it should be `.map` instead.

Try to define a type class and transfer implicit parameter from method level to class level

```
trait ToStr[T] {
  def apply(factors: ListBuffer[Int], fac: ListBuffer[Int] => Int, elems: T*): String
}
object ToStr {
  implicit val int: ToStr[Int] = 
    (factors, fac, elems) => elems.map((i: Int) => fac(factors) * i).toString
  implicit val str: ToStr[String] = (_, _, elems) => elems.toString
}

class Seq[T : Ordering] (initialElems: T*)(implicit toStr: ToStr[T]) {

  override def toString: String = toStr(factors, fac, elems: _*)

  ...
}
```

Otherwise `def toString(implicit ev: T <:< Int): String` doesn't override `def toString: String` indeed.

Comment: When I try to do override def toString: String = ToStr(factors, fac, elems: _*) it says 'Missing arguments for method fac(ListBuffer[Int])' and if I add factors as parameter to fac it says ''ToStr.type' does not take parameters'

Comment: @Anton What's your version of Scala? In 2.13.2 it compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/O7wcuTCBRWeGtkwSkhOXRA Try to replace `fac` with `fac(_)` in `toStr(factors, fac, elems: _*)`. Notice that it should be `override def toString: String = toStr...` with lower-case `toStr`.

Comment: I use 2.13.2 too and if I use toString with lower-case it says 'Cannot resolve symbol toStr'

Comment: @Anton `toStr` is implicit parameter `(implicit toStr: ToStr[T])` in the definition of `class Seq[T : Ordering] (initialElems: T*)(implicit toStr: ToStr[T])`!

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, didn't noticed it